# QR Code is not recognized by ZXing

Tags: qr-code, zxing

I've noticed that this qr-code is not recognized by the current version. I downloaded it from the wikipedia page about qr-codes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code its v25. I did test it in the online zxing decoder found here: https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

The Zbar app does not recognize it either. But apps like 'DataMatrix scanner' do without problems.

Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZXing only supports up to **v20** QR code at mobile client, you can find from the source codes, I attach the codes as follows:

`protected static final int MAX_MODULES = 97;` // support up to version 20 for mobile clients